# Button components aren't being properly disposed of with a new form

Tags: codenameone

I have three forms, each a separate .java class: Login, Registration, and Home.

On Registration I have text fields and buttons, displayed with:

```
Container c = TableLayout.encloseIn(2, TextField, Button);
```

With the simulator, if I go straight from Login to Home, it works perfectly fine. However, if I go from Registration (so the buttons load) to Login to Home, the buttons load in Home without the action listeners. They don't display on Login.

Here's the button code:

```
Button infoDOB = new Button("?","ButtonForInfo");
    infoDOB.addActionListener(e -> {
        ToastBar.showMessage("Select your birthday", FontImage.MATERIAL_INFO);
    });
```

I've tried infoDOB.remove() and this.removeAll() before navigating away from Registration and loading a new form, but it didn't change anything. Also tried System.gc() assuming it wouldn't work, and it didn't.

Am I missing something?

**edit**: I removed the GridBagLayout from Home and the issue has since not returned. Seems I got lucky.

Comment: I don't understand the description. Buttons are GC'd when they are no longer used and don't dispose. You don't show anything other than a toastbar in your button code. You don't need to dispose or explicitly call the GC. You don't need to remove components from their parent or form if you don't want to use them anymore as you're navigating to a different form.

Comment: That's what I understood, and yet they still "load" on a new form. I haven't needed to perform any removal for any other component on any other form so I don't know why this is so special.

Comment: A component can only be added to one form since it has a parent. If you try adding it to two forms it would throw an exception. Either code that adds a new button is invoked in the second form or you set the form to transparent which you shouldn't do and can cause weird bugs